# Problems with Hebrew in datepicker

Tags: datepicker, hebrew

I am using datepicker and I want it to work in Hebrew.
I found this: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization
but I don't want the user to choose a language. I want ths datepicker to work only in Hebrew.
How can I do that?
I tried this:

```
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['he']);
```

i got an answer from Sooriya Dasanayake but now I am trying to add date range and that doesn't work:

```
  from = $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+4w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showOn: "button",
        showAnim:"blind",
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "en-GB" ] );
        $( "#locale" ).change(function() {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option",
                    $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
        })
        }
  })
  .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
 to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showOn: "button",
        showAnim:"blind",
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "en-GB" ] );
        $( "#locale" ).change(function() {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option",
                    $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
        })
        }
  })
  .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });

  function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }

      return date;
    }

});
```

Comment: try `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "he" ] );`

Comment: it doesn't work. I tried '<script>  
  $( function() {
     $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "he" ] );
  });
 </script>
  </head>
<body><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" requiered>'

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
    jQuery(function($){
        $.datepicker.regional['he'] = {
                closeText: 'סגור',
                prevText: '&#x3C;הקודם',
                nextText: 'הבא&#x3E;',
                currentText: 'היום',
                monthNames: ['ינואר','פברואר','מרץ','אפריל','מאי','יוני',
                    'יולי','אוגוסט','ספטמבר','אוקטובר','נובמבר','דצמבר'],
                    monthNamesShort: ['ינו','פבר','מרץ','אפר','מאי','יוני',
                    'יולי','אוג','ספט','אוק','נוב','דצמ'],
                    dayNames: ['ראשון','שני','שלישי','רביעי','חמישי','שישי','שבת'],
                    dayNamesShort: ['א\'','ב\'','ג\'','ד\'','ה\'','ו\'','שבת'],
                    dayNamesMin: ['א\'','ב\'','ג\'','ד\'','ה\'','ו\'','שבת'],
                    weekHeader: 'Wk',
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    firstDay: 0,
                    isRTL: true,
                    showMonthAfterYear: false,
                    yearSuffix: ''};
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['he']);
});
```